# Testing neural network

Tags: neural-network

I have just finished writing a neural network implementation. I don't do the training myself so the only thing it should do is forward propagation, an incremental update of the input neurons and reading a csv file containing the weights/biases. I don't really know how to test these things (especially the first and last) though.

How do you test that forward propagation is working as it should?